# Scrapy crawler not recursively crawling next page

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

I am trying to build this crawler to get housing data from craigslist,

but the crawler stops after fetching the first page and does not go to the next page .

Here is the code , it works for the first page ,but for the love of god I dont understand why it does not get to the next page .Any insight is really appreciated .I followed [this part from scrapy tutorial](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html#more-examples-and-patterns)

```
import scrapy
import re

from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor




class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "craigslistmm"
    start_urls = [
        "https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/search/hhh"
    ]



    def parse_second(self,response):
        #need all the info in a dict
        meta_dict = response.meta
        for q in response.css("section.page-container"):
            meta_dict["post_details"]= {
                "location":
                    {"longitude":q.css("div.mapAndAttrs div.mapbox div.viewposting::attr(data-longitude)" ).extract(),
                "latitude":q.css("div.mapAndAttrs div.mapbox div.viewposting::attr(data-latitude)" ).extract()},

                "detailed_info":  ' '.join(q.css('section#postingbody::text').extract()).strip()

            }


        return meta_dict





    def parse(self, response):
        pattern = re.compile("\/([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/.+")
        for q in response.css("li.result-row"):

            post_urls = q.css("p.result-info a::attr(href)").extract_first()
            mm = re.match(pattern, post_urls)

            neighborhood= q.css("p.result-info span.result-meta span.result-hood::text").extract_first()




            next_url = "https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/"+ post_urls
            request = scrapy.Request(next_url,callback=self.parse_second)
            #next_page = response.xpath('.//a[@class="button next"]/@href').extract_first()
            #follow_url =  "https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/" + next_page
            #request1 =  scrapy.Request(follow_url,callback=self.parse)
            #yield response.follow(next_page,callback = self.parse)


            request.meta['id'] = q.css("li.result-row::attr(data-pid)").extract_first()
            request.meta['pricevaluation'] = q.css("p.result-info span.result-meta span.result-price::text").extract_first()
            request.meta["information"] =  q.css("p.result-info span.result-meta span.housing::text" ).extract_first()
            request.meta["neighborhood"] =q.css("p.result-info span.result-meta span.result-hood::text").extract_first()
            request.meta["area"] = mm.group(1)
            request.meta["adtype"] = mm.group(2)


            yield request
            #yield scrapy.Request(follow_url, callback=self.parse)

        next_page = LinkExtractor(allow="s=\d+").extract_links(response)[0]


        # = "https://vancouver.craigslist.ca/" + next_page
        yield response.follow(next_page.url,callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the `next_page` extraction using `LinkExtractor`. If you look in the look, you'll see duplicate requests being filtered. There are more links on the page that satisfy your extraction rule and maybe they are not extracted in any particular order (or not in the order you wish).

I think better approach is to extract exactly the information you want, try it with this:

```
next_page = response.xpath('//span[@class="buttons"]//a[contains(., "next")]/@href').extract_first()
```

Comment: there is only a single link that will be fetched by this ,I have tried diff way to build the next_page ,similar to what you mentioned ,but It did not work .

Comment: It worked for me (at least until my IP was blocked.. :-))

Comment: Not working for me ,same thing is happening,Its not going to the next page

Comment: @Bg1850 Did you remove the `.url` from first parameter in `response.follow()` in `yield` at the end, right? As now the `next_page` is plain str.

Comment: YES . I like to know how you think it worked for you . did u check the scrapy log stats and what was the value of `request_depth_max`

Comment: @Bg1850 I only checked log for `item_scraped_count` stats value and that it actually visited the pages (i.e. for `DEBUG: Crawled (200) ...`).